# Long loading Javascript (modal window)

Tags: javascript, html, optimization

On this site [http://nashedom.ru](http://nashedom.ru/) there are JS scripts. Most are fast.

The modalka fancybox pages (for login users, in user cabinet, page объявления -> добавление объявления) are very slow. In Chrome loading is 25-28 seconds. In Firefox - 2,5 seconds.

The data is taken out of context.

HTML:

```
{% load hosts %}
<div class="b-header">
    <div class="b-header__menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="b-menu">
                      <a>...</a>
                      <a>...</a>
                      <a>...</a>
                      <a>...</a>
                        <span class="b-menu__item btn_change-location">
                        <a href="#change-location" class="fancybox dashed">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            View ads on site:
                            {% if user.districts.all.count > 1  %}
                                {% for district in user.districts.all %}
                                    {% if forloop.last %}
                                        <span>{{ district }}</span>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <span>{{ district }},</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% for district in user.districts.all %}
                                    <span>{{ district }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if user.regions.all.count > 1  %}
                                {% for region in user.regions.all %}
                                    {% if forloop.last %}
                                        <span>{{ region }}</span>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <span>{{ region }},</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% for region in user.regions.all %}
                                    <span>{{ region }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if user.cities.all.count > 1  %}
                                {% for city in user.cities.all %}
                                    {% if forloop.last %}
                                        <span>{{ city }}</span>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <span>{{ city }},</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% for city in user.cities.all %}
                                    <span>{{ city }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                                View ads on site:
                        {% endif %}

                        </a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Templates modal window**

```
{% load hosts %}
{% load widget_tweaks static %}
<div id="change-location">
<form action="{% host_url "setlocation" host "www" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div id="chose-city-wrap">
        <div class="b-modal__title">Select your city</div>
        <p>
            <div class="b-modal__item">
                <span>{{ location_form.country.label }}</span>
                {{ location_form.country }}
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="b-modal__item">
                <span>{{ location_form.districts.label }}</span>
                {{ location_form.districts }}
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="b-modal__item">
                <span>{{ location_form.regions.label }}</span>
                {{ location_form.regions }}
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class="b-modal__item">
                <span>{{ location_form.cities.label }}</span>
                {{ location_form.cities }}
            </div>
        </p>


        <br />

        <div class="b-modal__item b-modal__item_btn">
            <input class="b-btn b-btn_red" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

**cities download form on the page where the brakes modal window!**

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>The territory of distribution of the ads</legend>

        {{ form.country|add_class:"b-input__input js-select" }}
        {{ form.districts|add_class:"b-input__input js-select chosen-select" }}
        {{ form.regions|add_class:"b-input__input js-select chosen-select" }}
        {{ form.cities|add_class:"b-input__input js-select chosen-select" }}
        {# form.geo|add_class:"b-input__input" #}

    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you explain it, you have a lot of data to get (countries, cities), if you do it in php, you will lock the page until you retrive all those datas.

To have a shorter loading time, you just have to make everything in js (ajax).

You load your page with the cities, countries, ... without data.

Once the page is loaded (document.ready), you call your ajax to fill your cities, countries and so on.

Comment: Thank you! But i can use django. But I try to do as you say